# External AndroidManifest.xml doesn't appear under project view pane

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest, android-gradle-plugin, external

I have been developing an Android project using Android Studio and Gradle.

My project's `AndroidManifest.xml` is located under an external folder.
I'm pointing to it using the following code in the `build.gradle` file:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile '..\\..\\..\\sources\\AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}
```

Everything works great, the project compiles and runs, except I can't locate the `AndroidManifest.xml` file under the project structure, when using the project view pane.

[image: Project Structure]

Maybe I need to add something else to the `build.gradle` file?

Comment: The project structure would shoud onlye from the root folder of the project .Open the manifest once using File --> Open and then use the Ctrl + tab shortcut to switch between files

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "The project structure would shoud onlye from the root folder of the project".
If i'm opening it with file --> open, it doesn't recognize it a valid manifest file, and shows a lot of lint errors.

Answer (score 0):

First - I don't see any reason to maintain manifest outside Android project. It's integral part of Android application so it should be in location where Android Studio can read it. Just copy it where it should be.

If you really need to have AndroidManifest.xml in external location, think about making symbolic link to location where Android Studio expects it to be.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Normally, I wouldn't recommend maintaining the manifest outside of the project scope either. But this is a given in this situation.

Symbolic linking is not a good solution for us, as we are using source control, which means that every team member on every machine will need to add the symbolic linking.
In addition, we'll need to remember to do this procedure for every new machine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can. When you use the project view pane, Android Studio displays all files in the project root, not all the files linked to your project (to test this, you can create a new file that's not linked to your project in the folder of your project and you'll be able to see it in Android Studio explorer).

Comment: This is not true. I'm also adding external sources with `java.srcDirs = ['..\\..\\some\\source\\path']` and the external sources are showing under the project pane.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't help you, then

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio (and IntelliJ), are build under the assumption that all of your source is in a single "project" folder. That is why the Project view only contains files in the project, it's designed to just show a file tree.

I just tested it, you can use the Android view (one of the other options in the screenshot you posted) to have your external Manifest appear. Some of the functionality is disabled or broken while editing though. This is possible because the Android view is meant to show all relevant source for your project, even if you have the odd requirement of an external manifest.

But please, consider moving it into your project directly or using a symbolic link. You'll be much happier.

Comment: Regarding the sources, I have multiple source folders which I add to gradle in the following way: `java.srcDirs = ['..\\..\\some\\source\\path', '\\..\\..\\..\\some\other\path']`. They all appear under the "project" view pane. As you said, some of the functionality is broken in the Android view, so using it is not a good solution for us.
Symbolic linking is also not a good solution for us, as we are using source control, which means that every team member on every machine will need to add the symbolic linking. In addition, we'll need to remember to do this procedure for every new machine.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a folder closer to the directory you're on or if needed, move it closer.  "..\sources\AndroidManifest.xml"

Comment: The AndroidManifest.xml location is a given in my situation. I can't move it closer.

Comment: If it is windows you are probably breaking the directory path by having it be too long.

Comment: No, it's not a length issue. Tried it with shorter paths. Also, I'm using longer paths with `java.srcDirs = ['..\\..\\some\\source\\path']`, and they work just fine.